# Why different error codes for same Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, error-code

I am doing one synchronization example. I got two exceptions which are having same details about exception. But with the error codes.

And both exceptions have the same `Inner Exceptions`

What is means? What Error Codes will tell us more than exceptions?
How to get the details about my error code.
Thanks in Advance

```
Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncException: A storage engine operation failed with error code 25051 (HRESULT = 0x80004005, Source IID = {0FB15084-AF41-11CE-BD2B-204C4F4F5020}, Parameters=(0, 0, 0, , , , )).

Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncException: A storage engine operation failed with error code 25009 (HRESULT = 0x80004005, Source IID = {0FB15084-AF41-11CE-BD2B-204C4F4F5020}, Parameters=(0, 0, 0, , , , )).
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `InnerException` to see if it gives you more information about it?

Comment: Yes @Pikoh. For both exceptions `Inner Exceptions` are same. so i am not posted in the question due to lengthyness.

Comment: I would get the full `.ToString()` on the exception for both errors and show it anyway even if they are identical. Wtihout it you are not likely to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: I think you should add an answer @Christian.K. I guess you are right, and in that list is the explanation of OP errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got cleaned after reading the documentation

Answer (score 2):

From the wording of the message it looks like these are SQL CE errors. If so, have a look [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171879(v=sql.110).aspx) for the meaning of the actual error codes. For .NET code that wraps native code, it is not uncommon that one managed exception, SyncException here, is used with multiple error codes in addition (most prominent example Win32Exception).

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.syncexception_members(v=sql.105).aspx) there seems to be no apparent way to get this numeric code.

However, whether you can really react differently in your code, depending on one error code or the other, is questionable anyway. Log the error with all details
and be done with it.